# jQuery webcam plugin - saving image

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, save, webcam

im having a hard time saving the image captured from the webcam using the jquery webcam plugin. 
here's the code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#camera").webcam({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        mode: "save",
        swffile: "jscam.swf",   
    });

    });
```

i am using the 'save' mode. in the body part..

```
<div id="camera"></div>
<a href="javascript:webcam.save('upload.php');void(0);">capture</a>
```

in the upload.php part..

```
$str = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("upload.jpg", pack("H*", $str));
```

i also tried the callback mode still doesnt work. it seems the blog itself has insufficient examples

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

[update]

finally got it working! i can capture the images. i dug up the source code of the page and added an onload eventlistener on my code :D

now my only problem is **how to save the image**. the blog doesn't clearly specify how. it just gave the codes

```
webcam.save('/upload.php');
```

which is honestly i don't know what to do with it, unlike the php code he gave. should i **put it in a link**? or **edit the onCapture part**?

Comment: Which part is failing? Is it getting to the PHP code fine, or is the error occurring with how the PHP file is getting the data etc?

Comment: `javascript:webcam.capture();changeFilter();void(0);` as suppose to save...look at the link `Take a picture instantly`

Comment: it doesn't display anything. @val the capture() function, I think it is only usable in the callback mode. like i said i am using the save mode. ill try later :)

Comment: you must capture it first according to his documentation... then save it, just read thru it properly :) hope it works for u

Comment: finally got it working. now my only problem is how to save the captured image in the server :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You going to need to do a little PHP Here is a basic upload script, from the JPEGCam project

```
<?php

/* JPEGCam Test Script */
/* Receives JPEG webcam submission and saves to local file. */
/* Make sure your directory has permission to write files as your web server user! */

$filename = date('YmdHis') . '.jpg';
$result = file_put_contents( '/path/to/file/store/or/site/' . $filename, 
      file_get_contents('php://input') );
if (!$result) {
    print "ERROR: Failed to write data to $filename, check permissions\n";
    exit();
}

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/' 
     . $filename;
print "$url\n";

?>
```

Comment: currently on another project but i guess this should be working :) gonna try it sooner

Comment: any idea why I get a broken image?