# jQuery webcam: Save mode results in: ''error: No save mode compiled in."

Tags: php, jquery, webcam, save

I am currently implementing a photo snapshot function to allow users to set their profile photo via webcam. To accomplish this, I am using [jQuery Webcam Plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/).

The problem arises in that I would like to have the user click a "Take Photo" and have the snapshot saved to the server in the appropriate location to be retrieved by the user image APIs.

It seems this should be pretty easy to do, but for some reason I am running into problems. When my button is pressed, the photo capture takes place alright, but the saving doesn't execute properly as I am receiving the error `error: No save mode compiled in.`

**NOTE: My Save URL contains a `hash` variable like `?hash=XYZ123`. This is how the image is named in the PHP file.**

I've attempted to remove the `hash` and `ref` variable from the url, thinking perhaps this caused the image data to be lost/ignored somehow, but that yielded no difference. Can anyone see something I did wrong here? I am pretty sure I followed the documentation as well as several other posts located here on SO, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570283/jquery-webcam-plugin-saving-image).

**Screenshot**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="camera"></div> <!-- WebCam Live Display -->
<div id="wcStatus"></div> <!-- Debug Text Display -->

<button onclick="showWebcam();">Use Webcam Instead</button>

<!--This button is normally hidden until camera initialized, but for sake for demo-->
<button onclick="saveWebCam('XYZ123', '66');">Take a picture!</button>
```

**JS**

```
function showWebcam(){
    $("#camera").webcam({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        mode: "save",
        swffile: "/webcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
        debug: function(type, string) {
            $('#wcStatus').append(type + ": " + string + '<br /><br />');
        }     
    }); 
}
function saveWebCam(hash, id){
    var url = '/accountFiles/userImages/saveFromWebCam.php?hash=' + hash + '&ref=' + randomString(30);
    $('#wcStatus').append('Capturing: ' + url + '<br /><br />');
    webcam.capture();
    webcam.save(url);
}
```

**PHP (saveFromWebCam.php)**

```
<?php
    $destFile=$_REQUEST['hash'].'.jpg';
    $str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    file_put_contents($destFile, pack("H*", $str));     
?>
```

**Debug Output**

> notify: Camera started
>
> Capturing: /accountFiles/userImages/saveFromWebCam.php
>
> notify: Capturing started.
>
> notify: Capturing finished.
>
> error: No save mode compiled in.

Comment: Are you sure you're using newest version of the plugin? As I can see at github the error message you've mentioned could coming from the actionscript file, but the line is commended out. Should checking this fail, try to check other forks of jquerycam plugin https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam/network/members (try for example lalop or nedforce forks).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I definately downloaded the newest version (more than once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, time constraints have forced me to seek alternatives to this project. I have decided, as many all over the web have, to use the [jpegCam Project](http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/). I got it up and running in about 15 minutes. SIMPLE! The only reason I am not deleting this question is for future seekers of such knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

This is your error:

```
swffile: "/webcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
```

should be:

```
swffile: "js/jscam.swf",
```

quote from [plugin webpage](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/):

> Points to the swf file of the Flash movie, which provides the webcam API. There are two swf files provided via the download archive: jscam.swf, which provides the full API and jscam_canvas_only.swf which have no embedded JPEG library (I embedded an adjusted JPGEncoder of the AS 3 corelib). Thereby, the file is only one third as large as the original.

Comment: I'll have to take your word for it at this point. Thank you for contributing to the thread, though.

Comment: I solved my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267772/php-code-to-asp-net-c-sharp with the answer of your question. LOL, just moved to jpegcam project!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance in return! :) Happy coding.